# Extract strings between two signs

Tags: excel, string, excel-formula

I'm doing some analysis in **Excel** and I'm trying to extract all strings between two chars (in this example, between two apostrophes - each string is between two ' ). I'd like to have each string in different cell (I know each of them will require different formula - I have no problem with that)
would love to understand how to do it

[image: This is the current status and what i would like to have]

Comment: Have you tried anything? Identified any functions that might help?

Comment: Hint: look at text-to-columns

Comment: That's not a *hint*; that's practically an *answer*, short of Googling it for him!  :-)

Comment: I tried building several formulas, totally forgot about Text-to-columns, thanks for the hint :) fixed it in seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With data in column **A**, in **B1** enter:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,3,LEN(A1)-4),"''","'")
```

and copy down.  Then in **C1** enter:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($B1,"'",REPT(" ",999)),COLUMNS($A:A)*999-998,999))
```

and copy both across and then down:

[image]

This will achieve in formula form the same result as *Text-to-Columns*.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about Text-to-columns. It solve my problem